# Meaning of "poured it on and poured it out"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this part of the song "[2 Out Of 3 Ain't Bad](http://www.lyricstime.com/meat-loaf-2-out-of-3-aint-bad-lyrics.html) " by Jim Steinman, I cannot understand the phrase "poured it on and poured it out":

> ...
>   And maybe you can cry all night
>   But that'll never change the way that I feel
>   The snow is really piling up outside
>   I wish you wouldn't make me leave here
>
> ***I poured it on and I poured it out***
>   I tried to show you just how much I care
>   I'm tired of words and I'm too hoarse to shout
>   But you've been cold to me so long
>   I'm crying icicles instead of tears
>   And all I can do is keep on telling you
>   ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's two different expressions:

**Pour it on** means to intensify your efforts, to try harder, to bring your full force to bear on the task at hand.   "Our team looked like they were playing a good game against the Chicago Bulls, but then Michael Jordan really poured it on, scoring 30 points in the third quarter alone, and we were toast."

**Pour it out** means to express your (generally previously-repressed) feelings or issues fully.  "At first she didn't want to talk, but I stayed there just holding her quietly, and eventually my daughter poured out all her boy troubles to me."

So when you combine them in the song lyrics, the singer has apparently had some issues with the subject of the song, and he finally worked up his nerve, threw his heart into it, and put his best effort into telling the subject all about how he really feels.